# Make command in console run without a \" at the end

Tags: java

I want to open a console window and write any command I want, from a string which varies depending on what I input. The problem is that no commands with a / or \ work because of the last / in the CMDs parameters.

I've tried removing and changing the parameters, but the CMD won't run correctly then.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K" + command + "\"");
```

I Want to be able to run any command (From the command string), even commands like cd C:\ which contains a / or \

Answer (score 0):

Commands *containing* slash or backslash work just fine in your code, with *or* without the extra `\"` at the end, e.g. `c:\windows\system32\winver` or `c:/windows/system32/winver`

`C:\` doesn't work because that isn't a valid CMD command, which if not a builtin (like `cd` or `set` or `if`) or `drive:` (or `:label`) must be a *filename* (either a pathname, or a simple name which is searched on `%PATH%`) which is a program (`.exe` or on older versions `.com`) or is associated to a program or is a `.bat` file. If you run CMD interactively and enter `C:\` it fails, and passing the same thing from Java can't make it work any better.

It *is* a valid 'command' in the Search-formerly-Run box, or the `start` command. Those, deliberately, accept some things that are not programs, and figure out how to 'open' them -- in particular they 'open' a directory name like `C:\` by running Explorer. Using your code to run `explorer c:\` does work.

Comment: Well, commands like "cd E:\" or "dir" doesn't work because of the last "\" here `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K" + command + "\""); ` basically makes the code like "cd E:\\" and "dir\". But without the "\" in the startup parameters no commands at all would run.

I'm don't think I will return to this project anyways but thanks for the help.

Comment: No, `"\""` (as a Java string literal) is an escaped quote not a quoted backslash and adding a quote makes them `cd E:\"` and `dir"` which work fine -- although the first has no visible effect if your current drive is C: as it usually is. And everything I try that actually is a valid CMD command (also) works fine without the quote.